# MySQL replication on cluster servers using Virtual IPs

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I'm trying to setup a MySQL replication. The problem is that the replication must be done between 2 cluster servers and the user used must be connected via the Virtual IP of the servers.

Configuration:

1. Add the needed host names in `/etc/hosts` - both servers

   ```
   # 10.0.1.34 - is the Virtual IP of the slave cluster
   # 10.0.1.45 - is the virtual IP of the master cluster
   10.0.1.34       mysqlslave
   10.0.1.45       mysqlmaster
   ```
2. Create the MySQL `repl` user and grant the access on both servers

   1. On Master Server:

      ```
       mysql -u root -pmy-password
       mysql> CREATE USER 'repl'@'mysqlslave' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';
       mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'mysqlslave';
       mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'repl'@'mysqlslave' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';
       mysql> exit;
      ```
   2. On Slave Server:

      ```
       mysql -u root -pmy-password
       mysql> CREATE USER 'repl'@'mysqlmaster' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';
       mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'mysqlmaster';
       mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'repl'@'mysqlmaster' IDENTIFIED BY 'my-password';
       mysql> exit;
      ```

Now, when I'm trying to check if the access was successfully granted by running the command (on the master server):

```
mysql -u repl -pmy-password -h mysqlslave
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'repl'@'10.0.1.46' (using password: YES)
```

where `10.0.1.46` is the IP of the Primary Node of the Master Cluster.

Why it is not using the Virtual IP when trying to connect?

**NOTE**: if I run the following command:

```
mysql -u repl -pmy-password -h mysqlslave --bind_address='10.0.1.45'
```

the connection is established, but I want to use this bind as default. I've already tried to change the `bind-address` parameter in `my.cnf` but without success.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment the solution was to add all the cluster IPs to the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
10.0.1.34       mysqlslave
10.0.1.35       mysqlslave
10.0.1.36       mysqlslave
10.0.1.45       mysqlmaster
10.0.1.46       mysqlmaster
10.0.1.47       mysqlmaster
```

If there is any other solution than the one I found, please comment them.